# Can't connect to NetSuite ODBC with Go on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, odbc, ubuntu-16.04, netsuite

I'm working with a NetSuite ODBC for the first time and I have a hard time connecting to it. I have installed the drivers but when I try to connect this is what I get:
`SQLDriverConnect: {01000} [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64/ivoa25.so' : file not found`

If I execute `ldd /opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64/ivoa25.so` this is what I get:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd9f94d000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fbefbdb0000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fbefbbac000)
libicuuc.so.42 => not found
libicudata.so.42 => not found
libpam.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0 (0x00007fbefb99e000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fbefb781000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fbefb3f5000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fbefb0ec000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fbefaed4000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fbefab0a000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fbefc35e000)
libaudit.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaudit.so.1 (0x00007fbefa8e3000)
```

Those 2 files which are marked as `not found` exists in the `/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64` directory, I'm not sure why are they marked as `not found`.

`odbcinst -j`

```
unixODBC 2.3.1
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /home/alen/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

`cat /etc/odbc.ini`

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
NetSuite=NetSuite ODBC Drivers 7.2

[NetSuite]
Driver=/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64/ivoa25.so
Description=Connect to your NetSuite account
Host=####
Port=####
ServerDataSource=######
Encrypted=1
Truststore=/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/cert/ca.cer, /opt/netsuite/odbcclient/cert/ca2.cer, /opt/netsuite/odbcclient/cert/ca3.cer
CustomProperties=AccountID=####;RoleID=####

[ODBC]
Trace=0
IANAAppCodePage=4
TraceFile=odbctrace.out
TraceDll=/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64/ddtrc25.so
InstallDir=/opt/netsuite/odbcclient
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Setting the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` it can solve the problem. It will work if you have the netsuite extracted file into `/opt/netsuite/odbcclient`

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
```

Additionally, consider the netsuite driver is compatible with Ubuntu 12.04, so it could have additional issues.